# Getting Error on Add Item Page in Admin UI Component

Tags: uicomponent, save, ui-form

I just created a Form with Ui_components, but When I go to this page, I'm getting the following error.

[image]

Comment: Can you check the magento log file?

Comment: It says :main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http://localhost/shop/index.php/admin/mastering/item/add/","invalidateInfo":{"identifier":"LOCKED_RECORD_INFO_BLOCK_32bf8d9e77b2800ea5013bd716edd6be3d224f32"}} []

Comment: Check your *Network* tab in browser developer tools for the response body to the failed (red) XHR request.

Answer (score 0):

Check the logs

var/log/execption.log

var/log/system.log

Comment: It says :main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate: {"method":"GET","url":"localhost/shop/index.php/admin/mastering/item/add/…":{"identifier":"LOCKED_RECORD_INFO_BLOCK_32bf8d9e77b2800ea5013bd716edd6be3d224f32"}} []

Comment: If there error is from one of the block class you used then you have to check those block class. Usually block class don't know error in this logs